# Angular jwt authentication fails when reloads the page

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to authenticate user through token. if i login then token will be created and stored in local storage. whenever there is a change in route I'm hitting the api which is built in express js , gives me decoded user value. everything works without refresshing page. Once I refresh the page I'm not able to hit the API. in order to get decoded user value i suppose to click on login button which is there in header , which triggers the route change then again everything works fine. Please help me out .

```
.controller('mainController', function($rootScope, $location, $window ,Auth){

        var vm = this;
        $rootScope.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(){
          $rootScope.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
            Auth.getUser()
                .then(function(data){
                    $rootScope.user = data.data;
                });
        });

        vm.login = function(){
        ......
        }

        vm.logout = function(){
        ......
        }
})
```

Service

```
.factory('Auth', function($http, $q, AuthToken){
    var authFactory = {};

    authFactory.login = function(username, password){

        return $http.post('/api/login', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
        .success(function(data){
            AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
            return data;
        });
    };

    authFactory.logout = function(){
        AuthToken.setToken();
    };

    authFactory.isLoggedIn = function(){
        if(AuthToken.getToken()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    authFactory.getUser = function(){
        if(AuthToken.getToken()){
            return $http.get('/api/me');
        } else {
            return $q.reject({ message: "User has no token"});
        }
    };

    return authFactory;
})
```

factory for setting token and interceptor code

```
.factory('AuthToken', function($window){
    var authTokenFactory = {};

    authTokenFactory.getToken = function(){
        return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    };

    authTokenFactory.setToken = function(token){

        if(token){
            $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        } else {
            $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
        }
    };

    return authTokenFactory;
})

.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location, AuthToken){
    var interceptorFactory = {};

    interceptorFactory.request = function(config){
        var token = AuthToken.getToken();

        if(token){
            config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
        }

        return config;
    };

    interceptorFactory.responseError = function(response){
        if(response.status == 403){
            $location.path('/login');
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
    };

    return interceptorFactory;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have to reset the $http default headers on refresh. Using cookies in my case, I make a call to the following function at the beginning of $on('$stateChangeStart'):

```
service.RefreshGlobalVars = function () {
    if ($http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken == null) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + $cookieStore.get('_Token');
        $http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken = $cookieStore.get('_RefreshToken');
    }
   };
```

edit- to clarify, since I haven't seen your setToken() function, your implementation may vary, but that's pretty much the gist of it.

Comment: I'm using localStorage for that. Even after refresh token will be there. It will destroyed once i logout .

Answer (score 0):

I got answer, solved it by checking route change in the main app.js, inside run block.

```
MyApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth){

  $rootScope.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(){
      $rootScope.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
        Auth.getUser()
            .then(function(data){
                $rootScope.user = data.data;
            });
    });
```